# Как в WP переименовать название стандартного поля в форме регистрации или добавить help-text?

Tags: wordpress

Использую стандартную форму регистрации WP, но заказчик хочет, чтобы поле "Имя пользователя" было явно указано: "вводить имя пользователя только латинскими буквами без пробелов".
Так как другое WP не воспринимает, а пользователи и правда бывают разные. 
Не хотелось бы использовать сторонние плагины. Кстати в тексте ошибки тоже не сказано, что буквы должны быть латинскими.

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой способ в вашем конкретном случае - это изменить перевод WordPress. Скачайте файл `/wp-content/languages/ru_RU.po`, с помощью `poedit` отредактируйте его. Замените перевод `"Username"` вместо `"Имя пользователя"` на `"Имя пользователя - вводить только латинскими буквами без пробелов"`. Сохраните `.po`.

Если затрудняетесь, можно `.po` изменить в текстовом редакторе в районе строки `10561` (для `WP 4.7.2`). Потом этот `.po` откройте с помощью `poedit` и сохраните.

После сохранение через `poedit` появится файл `.mo`. Закачайте его на сайт в папку, указанную выше, с перезаписью.

Все.

**UPDATE**

Как правильно отметили в комментариях, такой способ проживет лишь до обновления WordPress. Лучше вставить следующий код в `function.php` вашей темы:

```
function filter_gettext( $translated, $original, $domain ) {
    // Если не основной текстовый домен WP - ничего не делаем
    if ($domain !== 'default') return $translated;
    // Текстовая строка должна быть в точности такой, как в файле перевода
    if ( $translated == "Имя пользователя" ) {
        $translated = "Имя пользователя - вводить только латинскими буквами без пробелов";
    }
    return $translated;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'filter_gettext', 10, 3 );
```

В результате имеем:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Работающий пример [здесь](http://test.kagg.eu/wp-login.php?action=register).

Comment: ..и потерять при обновлении ;) лучше уж плагом типа https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/say-what/

Comment: KAGG Design, Благодарю! Действительно, то что нужно. И с обновлениями действительно косяк...

Comment: @SeVlad справедливое замечание. Добавил в ответ 10 строк кода, которые решают вопрос без плагинов и работают после обновления WP.

Comment: Если ответ помог, его можно отметить как принятый. Это поможет сориентироваться другим пользователям StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

> Не хотелось бы использовать сторонние плагины.

При многопользовательской системе нужно много чего сделать. В первую очередь по безопасности - начиная от запрета доступа в админку и заканчивая разными возможностями ролей. Так что плагинопаранойя - зло вообще, а тут просто большое зло.

См. [TML](https://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-my-login/) и др плагины для многопользовательских систем.

> Так как другое WP не воспринимает

[Allow cyrillic usernames](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/allow-cyrillic-usernames/): плагин позволяет использовать символы кириллицы в имени пользователя (логине).

Comment: Благодарю за ответ! Allow cyrillic usernames - не знала, что такое возможно. TML - не редактирует поля формы. Только меняет внешний вид.

Comment: Ваш правильный вариант можно услышать?

Comment: А что не понятно из моего ответа?

Comment: "Так что плагинопаранойя - зло вообще, а тут просто большое зло." Что именно большое зло? Что я не правильно делаю?

Comment: После "вводной речи" я же дал ссылку на TML Это один из плагинов, который позволяет и наладить многопользовательский функционал и сократить риски. Но конкретные решения зависят от конкретных задач. Про TML - про его шаблоны см в его документации. С ним легко можно можно сделать любую страницу (входа в тч) с любыми текстами и пр.

Comment: Собственно, в django была возможность перегрузки любой функции с переопределением полей (это не затрагивало ядро). Есть ли такое в WP? Как добавлять поля я нашла, как переименовать нет. И не хочется писать полностью новую для регистрации, если нужно только одно поле переименовать. И плагин ставить зачем, когда есть стандартные возможности. Считаю, что плагины хороши для расширения функционала. Правильно мыслю, или нет?

Comment: Конечно в ВП есть. ВП - это свое рода фреймворк, только "другого вида", так сказать. https://codex.wordpress.org/ru:API_WordPress.  А насчёт изменения текстовых строк перевода - в ВП используется механизм geеtext